# Speeding up a loop over rasters

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a big dataset with 30000 rasters. My goal is to extract a mean value using the polygon located within the raster and create a file with extracted rasters values and dates from rasters filenames.

I succeeded in doing this by performing the following loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(rasters2014)){
a <- raster(rasters2014[i])
ext[i] <- as.vector(extract(a, poligon2, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, df=F))
}
output2 = data.frame(ext, filename=filename2014)
```

The problem is that the presented above loop takes about 2.5h hours to complete the calculation. Does anyone have an idea how I could speed up this process?

Comment: It looks like you might be growing `ext` in a loop (not a good idea!). Try either initializing it to the length you need or use a different loop, for example: `out = lapply(rasters2014, function(x) {as.vector(extract(raster(x), poligon2, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, df=F))})`

Comment: Thanks for help! I've tried yours loop, but unluckily it doesn't speed up the operations. I can't narrow the length of the loop as I must do it for all 30000 elements.

Comment: If each raster has a single band you can stack the rasters into a multi-band raster and then call `extract` once (no loop) to get the mean within the polygon for all of the bands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your raster are all properly aligned (same ncol, nrow, extent, origin, resolution), you could try identifying the "cell numbers" to be extracted by looking on the first file, then 
extracting based on those. This could speed-up the processing beacause raster does not need to compute which cells to extract. Something like this:

```
rast1 <- raster(rasters2014[1])
cells <- extract(rast1, poligon2, cellnumbers = TRUE, df = TRUE)[,"cells"]
ext <- list()

for (i in 1:length(rasters2014)){
  a <- raster(rasters2014[i])
  ext[[i]] <- as.vector(extract(a, cells, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, df=F))
}
```

Note that I am also using a `list` to store the results to avoid "growing" a vector, which is usually wasteful.

Alternatively, as suggested by @qdread, you could build a rasterStack using `raster::stack(rasters2014, quick = TRUE)` and call `extract` over the stack to avoid the for loop. Don't know which would be faster.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If your polygons do not overlap (and in most cases they don't) an alternative route is

```
library(raster)
x <- rasterize(poligon2, rasters2014[1])
s <- raster::stack(rasters2014, quick = TRUE)
z <- zonal(s, x, "mean")
```

*PS*: Faster is nicer, but I would suggest getting lunch while this runs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! I've tried all of the proposed solutions and the computation time generally the same regardless of the applied method. Therefore, I guess that it is just not possible to significantly speed up the computational process.